# Invalid magic number when decompressing using javascript. Headers not added when compressing using lz4 in golang

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, lz4

I have an gin api in which i compress a string using lz4 frame compression and send the result in the response to a frontend. In the javascript I fetch that api and decompress the data using lz4 package by pierrec, at that time I am getting Invalid magic number error. Can anyone help me with this?

Backend

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "github.com/pierrec/lz4"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

var fileContent = `CompressBlock compresses the source buffer starting at soffet into the destination one. This is the fast version of LZ4 compression and also the default one. The size of the compressed data is returned. If it is 0 and no error, then the data is incompressible. An error is returned if the destination buffer is too small.`

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Define the API endpoint
    router.POST("/api/endpoint", func(c *gin.Context) {
        toCompress := []byte(fileContent)
        // compressed := make([]byte, len(toCompress))

        result, err := compress(toCompress)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"result": result})
    })

    // Start the server
    router.Run(":8000")
}

func compress(in []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    r := bytes.NewReader(in)
    w := &bytes.Buffer{}
    zw := lz4.NewWriter(w)
    _, err := io.Copy(zw, r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // Closing is very important
    if err := zw.Close(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return w.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Frontend

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import LZ4 from 'lz4';

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint';

const postData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Request failed with status ' + response.status);
    }
    const result = await response.json();
    // const decoded = base64ToArrayBuffer(result.result);
    const buffer = Buffer.from(result.result);
    const decompressed = LZ4.decode(buffer);
    const decodedBuffer = Buffer.from(decompressed);
    console.log(decodedBuffer.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

postData();
```

Error

```
Error: Invalid magic number: 4D466941 @0
    at Decoder.emit_Error (/home/anand/go/src/github.com/anand-dotworld/test/client/node_modules/lz4/lib/decoder_stream.js:64:22)
    at Decoder.read_MagicNumber (/home/anand/go/src/github.com/anand-dotworld/test/client/node_modules/lz4/lib/decoder_stream.js:93:8)
    at Decoder._main (/home/anand/go/src/github.com/anand-dotworld/test/client/node_modules/lz4/lib/decoder_stream.js:289:25)
    at Decoder._transform (/home/anand/go/src/github.com/anand-dotworld/test/client/node_modules/lz4/lib/decoder_stream.js:60:7)
    at Decoder.Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:184:23)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Decoder.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:609:17)
    at Object.LZ4_uncompress [as decode] (/home/anand/go/src/github.com/anand-dotworld/test/client/node_modules/lz4/lib/decoder.js:14:10)
    at postData (file:///home/anand/go/src/github.com/anand-dotworld/test/client/index.js:24:30)
```

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts in your question. Have you verified that your backend code, independent of HTTP, produces the correct output? In other words, how confident are you this is a problem sending and decoding compressed data over an HTTP connection versus a simple encoding error? Or, for that matter, a simple decoding error independent of the source of the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the JavaScript code. You should replace

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from(result.result);
```

with

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from(result.result, 'base64');
```

---

Here is the doc for [json.Marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal):

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, **except that []byte encodes as a base64-encoded string**, and a nil slice encodes as the null JSON value.

You see that the backend code encodes the `[]byte` as base64-encoded string.

But according to the doc for [Buffer.from(string[, encoding])](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding), the default value of `encoding` is `utf8`. So in order to decode the base64-encoded string, you should specify the encoding as `base64` explicilty.

---

I have tested with this configuration:

**go.mod**:

```
module m

go 1.20

require (
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
    github.com/pierrec/lz4 v2.6.1+incompatible
)

require (
    github.com/bytedance/sonic v1.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/chenzhuoyu/base64x v0.0.0-20221115062448-fe3a3abad311 // indirect
    github.com/frankban/quicktest v1.14.5 // indirect
    github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype v1.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/locales v0.14.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.18.1 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/validator/v10 v10.14.0 // indirect
    github.com/goccy/go-json v0.10.2 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9 // indirect
    github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.12 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/cpuid/v2 v2.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.19 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v1.0.2 // indirect
    github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2 v2.0.8 // indirect
    github.com/twitchyliquid64/golang-asm v0.15.1 // indirect
    github.com/ugorji/go/codec v1.2.11 // indirect
    golang.org/x/arch v0.3.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.10.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.8.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.9.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.30.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
)
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "lz4": "^0.6.5",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Run the js code with this command:

```
node index.js
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @ZekeLu . I have tried that already, but it returned the same error.

Comment: @AnandSamuel I have updated the answer to add the content of the `go.mod` and `package.json` files that I tested. If you still see the same error, please update the question to add a full demo that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AnandSamuel is there any update on the issue?